# Get dataHandler from a SOAP message

Tags: java, soap

I need a way to change the `dataHandler` field to `cid:generated cid`

How do I get the `dataHandler` element from the SOAP message?

This approach doesn't work:

```
env.getBody().getElementByID("datahandler")
```

Any help?

```
String cid = _messageContext.addAttachment(
    dispatchDocumentRequest8.getDataDescription().getDataHandler());

// create SOAP envelope with that payload
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope env = null;

env = toEnvelope(getFactory(
    _operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()),
    dispatchDocumentRequest8,
    optimizeContent(
        new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
            "dmsSOAP.fiso.denue.fisglobal.com",
            "dispatchDocument")));

env.getBody().getElementByID("datahandler"); // this is wrong
```

*Envelope:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:dispatchDocumentRequest>  
         <dataDescription>   
            <dataHandler>HERE</dataHandler>
         </dataDescription>
      </ns1:dispatchDocumentRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to search for a specific descendant, so just use getDescendants(false) and look for the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try it with camelCase, so instead of

`COPYenv.getBody().getElementByID("datahandler")`

Try the following:

`COPYenv.getBody().getElementByID("dataHandler")`

**EDIT**

According to your comment i think you should try:

`COPYenv.getBody().getElementByID("dataHandler").setText("something")`

Comment: getElementByID method doesn't exist.... it was an example. Also I need to set the value